# .ToShortDateString() format has changed on new server

Tags: asp.net, azure, globalization, datetime-format, windows-server-2012

I'm managing an asp.net 4.0 website with a backend written in c#.

After changing from a 2008 to a 2012 windows server (now on azure) the date time format has changed from Swedish to English.

I have tried to change the language setting on the server but it won't change on the site.

In the .Net Globalization setting the culture is set to "Invariant Language (Invariant Country)" but that was the same on the old server.

Anyone know what and where I need to change.

The site works as it should but I want to make sure the datetime format is correct without change the code.

Comment: Similar problem here, regional settings at os level culture set to Dutch (Belgium) and application runs under culture Frech (Belgium). And format changed from "d/MM/yyyy" to "dd-MM-yy".